# Unable to ISP program my ATtiny85 with Atmel ICE

Tags: avr, avrdude

I'm trying to program my ATtiny85 with Atmel ICE but I get this error:

> avrdude: stk500v2_command(): unknown status 0xcc avrdude:
>   initialization failed, rc=-1
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check.

Does anyone know what problem is?

Comment: Schematic for your board, please.

Comment: What avrdude command are you using?

Comment: Are you providing 5V to the ATTiny? (The Atmel ICE doesn't supply power)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned in unanswerable condition for two years

Comment: @Chris I made an attempt to provide a useful "frequent problems" answer to address this for future visitors.

Comment: The two problems are that as an *abandoned* question it will likely never have an accepted answer.  And as a *terribly incomplete* question it's an example of what NOT to do when asking - especially where the specific requests for clarification were *ignored*.

Answer (score 2):

Common causes for this:

1. Atmel ICE doesn't supply power to the microcontroller (as Tom mentioned in comments). It has a green LED that indicates target power, but you need to supply power separately.
2. Make sure the `RESET` pin is not being held high by other parts of your circuit. The Atmel ICE needs to be able to pull it low during programming.
3. Double check connections - just as the error suggests. I've been guilty of having MISO and MOSI swapped, having a loose wire, and [having the microcontroller inserted into a breadboard backward](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/72908/2028).
4. Make sure that the fuses haven't been set to prevent writing to the microcontroller. A good example is the [`RSTDISBL` fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/22695/2028). If that has been set, you have to use a high voltage programming mode to get around it.
5. Swap the microcontroller out for a known working one. It's possible that the one you're trying to program has died (from static, high voltage or current, etc).