# Atmel ice Connection Issue with "device signature"

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, atmel, debugging

I have recently got a atmel ice and am having trouble programming it. I have been trying to connect it a attiny2313-PU. I am confident that I have wired it up correctly. The problem is when I look for the device signature I will get an error of

"Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)

Unable to enter programming mode. Verify device selection, interface settings, target power, security bit, and connections to the target device."

I dont think it is a fuse problem as I cant access any fues in debug or isp mode. If you guys have any ideas that would be helpful.

Comment: You forgot to power the target. The ICE adapts to different target power levels, hence the VCC connection, but it cannot send powert to the attiny µC.

Comment: I have powered the target as I get a +4.8v on target read and a green light on the ice

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/311341/2028

Comment: One possibility is the interface speed. Try a really low speed, since some chips are default set to xtal/8 and prog speed needs to be much less thn this.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse me for my English level. I recently encountered the same difficulty and didn't found any solution on the web despite many hours of research.

In my case, the microcontroller was plugged on a breadboard but there weren't any faulty contact. The problem came from the atmel ice and more precisely the connection between the six wires and the ISP connector.

In fact in the Atmel ice datasheet (Table 3-5. Atmel-ICE SPI Pin Mapping  -  page 17), the connection is described like below :

- pin 1 : MISO
- pin 2 : VCC
- pin 3 : SCK
- pin 4 : MOSI
- pin 5 : RESET
- pin 6 : GND

But in the reality, after checking the connections, I noted that the connections was like below :

- pin 1 : RESET
- pin 2 : GND
- pin 3 : SCK
- pin 4 : MOSI
- pin 5 : MISO
- pin 6 : VCC

I don't know if this pins layout is the same for all the Atmel Ice. So you can check on your device (the wire number one is darker) and adapt the connection between your ISP connector and your microcontroller.